# Does reality change? when you many theories

Tags: philosophy-of-science, reality

for example things appear and disappear.

Comment: it seems reality changes but maybe you should believe that it doesnt

Comment: ive seen how it changesfor exampleonce that i believed that it doesnt found weird things or something in a place a room things that doesnt have any explanation

Comment: "Reality" usually refers to something that exists independently of what we think of it. A.k.a. a collection of facts that are the same for everyone, can be asserted, agreed upon and used as a cornerstone for discussion, independently of anyone's thought. If reality changes because of our theories about it, reality is not reality anymore. Think about what happens if different people have different theories: does each person have their own reality ?

Comment: but how can you prove if reality changes or not

Comment: one way that i believe can be done to know is taking a photo of something for example a table game or something which have many pieces and you think something for example you can opensomething a box or something very quickly and take a picture of it and then see if reality changes or not

Comment: If there is a connection between the first two sentences and the third it would help to fill it in. If one at least switched from one theory to another that would be a change, just standing in between them like a Buridan donkey is entirely static.

Comment: The fundamental assumption of *scientific knowledge* is that there is a "reality" out there and we can know it at least in part and approximately. If we have multiple theories that fit with the reality, this means that they are incomplete description of the world and that we have either: (i) try new experiments/observations aimed to deepen our knowledge of the facts, or (ii) add new hypothesis/refine our theories in order to discriminate between them.

Comment: And "reality" changes every day, every moment: the clouds in the sky, people moving around the world, stock indices... Maybe you have to be a little bit more specific.

Comment: i mean that reality is changes in a weird way for example if the soul and cell exist maybe cells would stop existing and our mind wouldchange tooso that we dontrealize the change but we would still realize

Comment: i think the word i was going to use is forked that really is forked but imnot sure what word to use

Comment: Paradigms shifting is essentially reality changing. You seem though to be asking about underdetermination, which is not. I wrote an answer that included reference to peer-to-peer reality, and network-created histories like blockchain, where forks would be relevant - paradigm creation, if you like. Photographs are just one form of record. You would want to compare many records, and types & sources of data, and find commonalities. I don't believe objectivity can be experienced, accessed, or is meaningful. No one experiences it, it is inaccessible (noumena).

Comment: [Parmenides](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parmenides) argued that change is impossible.   [Heraclitus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heraclitus) argued that change is the only thing that is permanent.

Comment: "However, in that Nietzsche grasps his own thinking (the doctrine of the will to power as the "principle of the new dispensation of value") in the sense of the actual completion of nihilism, he no longer understands nihilism only negatively as the devaluation of the highest values,

Comment: but rather also positively, as the overcoming of nihilism; for the reality of what is real as that reality is now explicitly experienced, the will to power, has become the origin and measure of a new dispensation of values. The values of this dispensation of values directly determine human representation and likewise fuel human transactions.  Being human is raised into a different dimension of occurring." Page 187, [Nietzsche's Word](https://html.pdfcookie.com/02/2019/12/17/zmlykqjxmov0/zmlykqjxmov0.html)

Comment: Reality revolutions don't come about very often.

Answer (score 1):

Theories are human-crafted descriptions which are approximations of reality. Reality is under no obligation to change in any way based on our *descriptions* of it.

Comment: but do you know what i mean i dont know how to explain you this for example if you worry too much with you brain for someone for example a relative or family and you suddenly stop worrying and at the same time you forget everything in your life for exampleyou have many theories about for example i thought that it was because i forgot everything and my brain soulor the soul of my brain was stuck until i remembered everything but there could be other theories thats an example only there could be more example of what i mean how can you prove if reality changes or not

Comment: what i mean is that i ve seen how reality changes i mean our own mind changes in this case in this theory for example things change for example documents etcetera for people appear and disappearour own minds dont let us see how reality changes

Comment: for example i ve seen devices which have weird behaviours like cameras for example i dont remember where i saw this and i ve seen for example how things change physically this doesnt prove off course that reality changes but i believe it does

Comment: but maybe you should believe that reality doesnt change until we have confirmation

Comment: for example it seems as if reality changed for mebecause for examplei dont see cells or i dont feel the perceive them

Comment: for example it seems as if reality changed for me because for example i dont see cell or i dont feel them i dont perceive them in any way i see biologicalthings are simple things are things mae out of simple chemicals with souls for example a fruit or an animal

Comment: @joseph: It sounds like you might be getting at the way we can group or interpret events, such that unexpected  changes have happened, eg conservation laws violated, things appear/disappear unaccountably.

Comment: I've heard it said that engineers say that their equations are an approximation of reality, while physicists say that reality is an approximation of their equations.

Comment: @Sandejo, that's humorous. I will respond with the physics laugh: r dr dr d(theta)